# How to include built maven (JAR) in docker build step

Tags: docker, maven, build, jar, include

I don't use docker multi-stages build.

I already built maven to JAR file with Jenkins pipeline.

```
mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package -Dmaven.test.skip
```

Result file located at `/home/app/target/myfile.jar`

After that i want to include this JAR file while build docker image.

I use this command in dockerfile.

```
COPY /home/app/target/myfile.jar /myfile.jar
```

But i got error when build docker.

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder199377670/home/app/target/myfile.jar: no such file or directory
```

I understand that absolute path is dynamic.

Please help suggest. How to specific location of JAR file.

**Edit: Already moved file to same path with Dockerfile but still not work.**

I tried to copy file with pipeline and verify that file is locate same path with Dockerfile.

```
2022-09-16 12:06:36  + cp /home/app/target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar sourceCode/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2022-09-16 12:06:36  + cd sourceCode
2022-09-16 12:06:36  + ls
2022-09-16 12:06:36  Dockerfile
2022-09-16 12:06:36  myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And in Dockerfile, I add this copy command.

```
COPY /myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /myapp-docker.jar
```

But when build docker. It still cannot find source file.

```
2022-09-16 12:06:53  Step 3/5 : COPY /myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /myapp-docker.jar
2022-09-16 12:06:53  COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder691591658/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Please add complete Dockerfile to the description of question.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute path of your jar file must refer to an absolute path within the docker build context, not an absolute path of your host. All the resources you want to copy into docker image must refer to the location of Dockerfile.

If e.g. the Dockerfile is in `/home` folder then it is the root folder , i.e. `/` within the docker build contex and the `COPY` command will be:

```bash
COPY /app/target/xxxx.jar /path/to/appfolder/in/image/xxxx.jar
```

Check this [page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) for further information.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to copy file with pipeline and build it again.

Comment: I already tried copy file to same location with dockerfile but still not work. Please view in Edit section.

Comment: Can you please check if ```.dockerignore``` has an entry with folder containing jar-file or jar-file itself? If not try again with ```COPY myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar myapp-docker.jar```.

Comment: Now i found root case. If i run docker build command with specific dockerfile path in folder (-f folder/dockerfile) it will failed to copy. 
But if i access that folder first and run docker build (-f dockerfile) It will can copy.

Comment: But I found another interesting point.
If i use COPY command with / (COPY /myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /myapp-docker.jar) It don't have any error while copy but I cannot found jar file in result image.
But if i use COPY command without / (COPY myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar myapp-docker.jar). I will found jar file in result image.

Comment: If you have still the problem, please update the question. Also, as commented your question please add your Dockerfile and build command, otherwise one can not reproduce the error and help you effectively.

Comment: I don't have any question. Thank you very much.

Comment: So, did defining docker build context solve the problem? In not, can you please describe how did you solved it?